# MessageConnection.receive() stops due some reason

Tags: blackberry, sms, capture

I am working on a blackberry application which captures SMS messages from the device. 
But somehow the MessageConnection.receive() does not receive the messages, or notifyIncomingMessage is not called, due to some unknown *event*.

And we are still capturing the outgoing messages from the device.

I don't have user's device access to check the log. Here is the code to capture incoming/outgoing messages.

....

```
MessageConnection mconn = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:0"); 
mconn.setMessageListener(this);

....

public void notifyIncomingMessage(MessageConnection conn) {

    try
    {
         Message m = _mc.receive();
         String address = m.getAddress();
         String msg = null;
          if ( m instanceof TextMessage )
          {
               TextMessage tm = (TextMessage)m;
               msg = tm.getPayloadText();
               sendToServer(msg);
          }          
          else
               { // do nothing}
    }
    catch(Exception ee)
    {
        LogError(ee);
    }
}


public void notifyOutgoingMessage(javax.wireless.messaging.Message message) 
{

    TextMessage tmsg = (TextMessage)msg;
    String msgtPayload = tmsg.getPayloadText(); 
        sendToServer("OUT",msgtPayload);
}
```

Please advise, how I can fix this bug/issue?

Salman

Comment: Is there some reason you're using _mc instead of conn in notifyIncomingMessage()? I assume you set _mc = mconn, but not the best practice. Without knowing what, if any, exception is thrown it may be hard to diagnose.

Comment: @Richard: I tried to make the code simple for this post. It is --> Message m = mconn.receive();

Comment: Ok, like I said without knowing about any exceptions I'm going out on a limb. I have noticed that when listeners are called the process context is not always what you would expect. You should probably be using the MessageConnection object passed in, or at least follow the example in the API docs and check to see if it is the object you expect. But like I said, this is me out on a limb. A more mundane casue could be an Exception from one of the other statements.

Comment: I have just found this about MessageConnection.setMessageListener(object) --> "There can be at most one listener object registered for a MessageConnection object at any given point in time. Setting a new listener will de-register any previously set listener" . Is it possible that my class event (notifyIncomingMessage) not call when some other application register MessageConnection.setMessageListener(object)?

Comment: Only if you have passed the MessageConnection object to that other application so it can register a listener on it.